# Socket.io Status 500 in Laravel-echo-server

Tags: laravel, apache, socket.io, broadcasting, laravel-echo

Im trying to get working Laravel Broadcasting with laravel echo server and Redis.

In development environment it works perfectly, but in production when I start echo server, the browser shows me:

[image: Browser response]

```
https://example.com/socket.io/$EIO=3&transport=polling&t=XXXXX , Status: 500 Internal Server Error,  Type: xhr
```

Also if I try to get the `socket.io.js` file at  `https://example.com:6001/socket.io/socket.io.js` it throws `ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT` while it works in development!

I am working in Centos 7 with Apache 2.4.6

This is my httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf config

```
 ProxyPass /socket.io/ws/ wss://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
 ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ws/ wss://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
 ProxyPass /socket.io/ https://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
 ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ https://127.0.0.1:6001/socket.io/
```

I think it could be a firewall trouble, or maybe something with SELinux?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56866032/configuring-apache-reverse-proxy-for-hosting-laravel-echo-server-on-production#_=_